# Error formulario SMTP con PHPmailer desde Godaddy

Tags: phpmailer, smtp, godaddy

Me estoy quemando la cabeza con este problema. Traté de leer e intentar todo lo posible antes de molestarlos, pero realmente me siento excedido.

Estoy queriendo configurar un formulario de contacto, con *PHPmailer*, en un hosting *Linux*, de *GoDaddy*.

Desde *GoDaddy* se advierte lo siguiente:
https://ar.godaddy.com/help/enviar-correo-de-formulario-usando-un-servidor-de-retransmision-smtp-953?

Pero pruebo con esas configuraciones y no me sirve.

Adjunto mi código php, y el error que rastreo con debug.

Código del procesar.php:

```
<?php  

require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");

if ( !isset($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["email"])  || !isset($_POST["asunto"])  || !isset($_POST["msg"]) ) {
    die ("Es necesario completar todos los datos del formulario");
}


// Llamando a los campos
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$correo = $_POST['email'];
$titulo = $_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje = $_POST['msg'];
$destinatario = "mimail@gmail.com" ;

// Valores enviados desde el formulario


$smtpHost = "midominio.com";  // Dominio alternativo brindado en el email de alta 
$smtpUsuario = "contacto@midominio.com";  // Mi cuenta de correo
$smtpClave = "(micontraseña)";  // Mi contrase帽a


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";


// VALORES A MODIFICAR //
$mail->Host = $smtpHost; 
$mail->Username = $smtpUsuario; 
$mail->Password = $smtpClave;


$mail->From = $email; // Email desde donde env铆o el correo.
$mail->FromName = $nombre;
$mail->AddAddress($destinatario); // Esta es la direcci贸n a donde enviamos los datos del formulario


$mail->Subject = "Email desde tu sitio web"; // Este es el titulo del email.
$mensajeHtml = nl2br($mensaje);



$mail->Body = "
<html> 

<body> 

<h1>Recibiste un nuevo mensaje desde el formulario de contacto</h1>

<p>Informacion enviada por el usuario de la web:</p>

<p>nombre: {$nombre}</p>

<p>correo: {$correo}</p>

<p>asunto: {$asunto}</p>

<p>mensaje: {$mensaje}</p>

</body> 

</html>

<br />"; // Texto del email en formato HTML
$mail->AltBody = "{$mensaje} \n\n "; // Texto sin formato HTML
// FIN - VALORES A MODIFICAR //

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$estadoEnvio = $mail->Send(); 
if($estadoEnvio){
header('Location:https://www.midominio.com/mensaje-recibido');
    exit();
} else {
    header('Location:https://www.midominio.com/error-mensaje');
        exit();

}

?>
```

El rastreo debug me tira lo siguiente:

> ```
> Connection: opening to lopezlacuara.com:25, timeout=300, options=array
> ( 'ssl' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' =>
> true,)
>     Connection: opened
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2
> Mon, 01 Feb 2021 08:45:55 -0700 "
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2
> Mon, 01 Feb 2021 08:45:55 -0700 "
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2
> Mon, 01 Feb 2021 08:45:55 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of
> this system to transport unsolicited, "
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 and/or bulk e-mail."
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Mon, 01 Feb 2021 08:45:55 -0700 220-We do not
> authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or
> bulk e-mail.
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO midominio.com
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]250-SIZE 52428800"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH
> PLAIN LOGIN"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com
> [208.109.42.14]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH
> PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS"
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello lopezlacuara.com [208.109.42.14]250-SIZE
> 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250
> HELP
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<>
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK"
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<miemail@gmail.com>
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted"
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself"
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 1 Feb 2021 15:45:55 +0000
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: To: miemail@gmail.com
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: From: alvaro ochoa martinez <>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Email desde tu sitio web
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <74d6dc4af97a031d1e88afeb5071ed91@midominio.com>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.17 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_74d6dc4af97a031d1e88afeb5071ed91"
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_74d6dc4af97a031d1e88afeb5071ed91
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: sasdsa dsadsadsadsa
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_74d6dc4af97a031d1e88afeb5071ed91
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <html>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <body>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <h1>Recibiste un nuevo mensaje desde el formulario de contacto</h1>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>Informacion enviada por el usuario de la web:</p>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>nombre: alvaro ochoa martinez</p>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>correo: alvaritochoamartinez@gmail.com</p>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>asunto: </p>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>mensaje: sasdsa dsadsadsadsa</p>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: </body>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: </html>
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: <br />
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_74d6dc4af97a031d1e88afeb5071ed91--
>     CLIENT -> SERVER:
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: .
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK id=1l6bOl-005MWm-Lg"
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1l6bOl-005MWm-Lg
>     CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>     SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net closing connection"
>     SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 p3plzcpnl445406.prod.phx3.secureserver.net closing connection
>     Connection: closed
> ```

Si alguien me puede ayudar me vendría bárbaro, estoy perfidísimo y mareado!

Comment: cual es el correo o el dominio que utilizas para enviar el correo? muchos dominios no brinda el servicio de smtp.... por lo general algunos recurren a gmail u otro proovedor para ello...

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de que sea por que lo hayas censurado, pero el remitente parece no ser válido: `MAIL FROM:<>`, `From: alvaro ochoa martinez <>`, etc. Muchos MTAs rechazan mensajes de correo cuyo remitente no es válido.

Comment: El dominio que utilizo para mandar el correo es el que cree en mi hosting godaddy .. como es Linux, tengo que poner como server el de localhost... censure algunas cosas, otras se me pasaron por alto.. pero evidentemente es un problema con el servidor email

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta. Deberías usar el servidor SMTP de tu servicio de correo electrónico. Si usas otro cualquiera los detectores de SPAM podrían determinar que el servidor que envió el correo no es el autorizado (sobre todo si tu proveedor usa DMARC, o solo SPF y/o DKIM por separado).